# JavaScript placement issue in tinyMce with custom theme

Tags: 7, javascript, wysiwyg

Just created a custom theme, everything works perfectly, but the buttons inside the tinyMce editor like `bold, copy, paste` doesn't show in the text area when the

```
<?php print $scripts; ?>
```

is placed at the bottom of the page (I mean before `</body>` tag)

It works perfectly when `js` files are placed at `head`. Is there any way I can follow best practices and place `javaScripts` at `footer` and also make the `tinyMce` buttons appear.

Comment: which best practices are you referring to?

Comment: @Aboodred1 It's considered good practice to place javascript in the footer where possible.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329807/benefits-of-loading-js-at-the-bottom-as-opposed-to-the-top-of-the-document has more information

Comment: @Clive True in regards of javascript, but have you tried to use this method with Drupal before? also check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271276/is-the-recommendation-to-include-css-before-javascript-invalid#9272730

Comment: @Aboodred1, I was referring to Steve Sounders guide about web speed. But your link just distracted me !!!

Comment: @JhilkeDai Sorry for distracting you. I tried your approach by placing scripts at the bottom before body tag, and I endup having a lot of problems with different modules.